# Is the 'spin' of Earth and the 'spin' of Mars a significant contribution to their angular momentum?

Tags: orbit, earth, mars, rotation, eccentricity

Is the 'spin' of Earth and the 'spin' of Mars taken into account as a contribution to the conservation of angular momentum? (and a contribution to the increasing/decreasing eccentricity?) Or - is the spin regarded as too small to be measurable?

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of angular momentum of each planet: orbital angular momentum of the planet around the Sun, and rotational angular momentum of the planet around its rotational axis.

Orbital angular momentum $L_{orb}$ is typically calculated at perihelion or aphelion as $L_{orb}=mvr$, where $m$ is the mass of the planet, $v$ is the instantaneous orbital velocity and $r$ is the distance between the center of the Sun and the center of the planet. For Earth, $L_{orb} \approx 2.7 \times 10^{40}$ kg m<sup>2</sup>/s.

Rotational angular momentum is $L_{rot} = I\omega$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\omega$ is the rotation rate. For Earth, $L_{rot} \approx 7.1 \times 10^{33}$ kg m<sup>2</sup>/s.

**As we can see for Earth, the rotational angular momentum is negligible when compared to the orbital angular momentum.  Mars will have a similar result.**

$L_{rot}$ and $L_{orb}$ are instantaneously independent. That is, one can't determine the spin rate of a planet by knowing its orbit or vice-versa. However, angular rotational momentum can be transferred into orbital angular momentum through tidal interactions such as [tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking). The total angular momentum of the system (including the rotational momentum of the larger body) is conserved.

Comment: `+1` My head spins when I think about angular momentum; this is a very grounded and thorough answer! Technically, *I think that* we can calculate (and also conserve) angular momentum about any point in space, but the center of mass of the planet, and the planet-Sun barycenter are the two most useful points to use unless a rogue star enters the solar system... :-0

Comment: "My head spins when I think about angular momentum" - You only have to think about it, not act it out! :)

Comment: @uhoh Yes, angular momentum is conserved about any point you care to choose. An easy but unenlightening proof is that physics is unchanged by a rotation about any point, and now Noether’s theorem applies.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft thanks for that :-)